# Writing to a file adds weird content at the end of the line

Tags: php, xml

I am working on a program that parses text files uploaded by a user and then saves the parsed XML file on the server. However, when I write the XML file I get some the text

```
&#xD;
```

at the end of each line. This text is not in my original text file. I didn't even notice it until I opened the new XML file to verify that it was righting all of the content. Has anyone ran into this before and if so can you tell me if it's due to the way I'm creating and writing my file?

**fileUpload.php** - These 3 lines occur when the user uploads the file.

```
$fileName = basename($_FILES['fileaddress']['name']);
$fileContents = file_get_contents($_FILES['fileaddress']['tmp_name']);
$xml = $parser->parseUnformattedText($fileContents);
$parsedFileName = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . ".xml";
file_put_contents($parsedFileName, $xml);
```

**parser.php**

```
function parseUnformattedText($inputText, $bookName = "")
{
   //create book, clause, text nodes
   $book = new SimpleXmlElement("<book></book>");
   $book->addAttribute("bookName", $bookName);

   $conj = $book->addChild("conj", "X");

   $clause = $book->addChild("clause");

   $trimmedText = $this->trimNewLines($inputText);
   $trimmedText = $this->trimSpaces($inputText);
   $text = $clause->addChild("text", $trimmedText);
   $this->addChapterVerse($text, "", "");

   //make list of pconj's for beginning of file
   $pconjs = $this->getPconjList();

   //convert the xml to string
   $xml = $book->asXml();   

   //combine the list of pconj's and xml string
   $xml = "$pconjs\n$xml";
   return $xml;
}
```

**Input text file**

```
1:1 X
it seemed good to me also,
X
having had perfect understanding of all things from the very first
to write you an orderly account, [most] excellent Theophilius
and
1:4
that
you may know the certainty of those things in which you were instructed

1:5 X
There was in the days of Herod, the king of Judea and a certain priest named Zacharias
X
his wife[was] of the daughters of Aaron
and
her name [was] Elizabeth.
1:8 So
it was,
that
while he was serving as priest 1:9 before God in the order of his division,
1:10 and
the whole multitude of the people was praying outside at the hour of incense
but
therefore
it was done.
```

Comment: maybe this one? `$xml = "$pconjs\n$xml";
`

Comment: I don't think so because it's showing up before the newline.

Comment: well its hard to know from this side, we don't know whats the incoming input anyway

Comment: I just added the content from an input file.

Answer (score 0):

`&#xD;` is the ASCII character for `\r\n` which doesn't seem to come out correctly from `parseUnformattedText()`.

Try `$xml = nl2br($parser->parseUnformattedText($fileContents));`

Comment: That adds a HTML line break to the end of each line in the file. It doesn't fix the \r\n that's already there now.

Comment: Correct. I did not know you wanted to remove it all together. However, now that you know what the problem is there are a handful of PHP options you have to get your desired outcome. For example, [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) might help you get rid of both the `&#xD;` string or `<br />` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of Seroczynski's answer I was able to create a function that trimmed removed any carriage returns from the text. The XML output looked fine after that. Here's the function I used to fix the issue:

```
function trimCarriageReturns($text)
{
   $textOut = str_replace("\r", "\n", $text);
   $textOut = str_replace("\n\n", "\n", $textOut);
   return $textOut;
}
```